# Combobox doesn't display SelectedIndex On Startup in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I am working on a WPF app where I need to work with comboboxes. I need to add items in the combobox and set the selectedindex in xaml. I have done it successfully but SelectedIndex doesn't appear when I run the application. Here is my code:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrequencyList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Name="comboBox1" />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding ModesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModesList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="2" Name="comboBox2" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> _FreqList;
_FreqList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> _CodecModes;
_CodecModes= new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ViewModel()
{
        _FreqList.Add("8 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("11.025 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("12 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("14.7 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("16 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("22.050 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("24 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("29.4 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("32 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("44.100 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("48 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("88.2 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("96 kHz");
        _FreqList.Add("undef");

        _CodecModes.Add("None");
        _CodecModes.Add("A Loop");
        _CodecModes.Add("DSP");
        _CodecModes.Add("I2S");            
}

public ObservableCollection<string> FrequencyList
    {
        get { return _FreqList; }
        set
        {
            _FreqList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FrequencyList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selected Frequency List
    /// </summary>
    private string _selectedFrequencyList;
    public string SelectedFrequencyList
    {
        get { return _selectedFrequencyList; }
        set
        {
            _selectedFrequencyList = value;
            int Listvalue = FrequencyList.IndexOf(_selectedFrequencyList);
            int ListFinalVal = Listvalue + 1;
            SelectedFreq(ListFinalVal);
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFrequencyList");
        }
    }

    public void SelectedFreq(int Select)
    {            
        int cmd = 0;
        int numBytes = 0;           

        cmd = ((0x8F00 & 0x7F00) | (m_slot & 0xFF));
        sendBuf[numBytes++] = Convert.ToByte(Select - 1);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ModesList
    {
        get { return _CodecModes; }
        set
        {
            _CodecModes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ModesList");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Selected Modes List
    /// </summary>
    private string _selectedModesList;
    public string SelectedModesList
    {
        get { return _selectedModesList; }
        set
        {
            _selectedModesList = value;
            int Modevalue = ModesList.IndexOf(_selectedModesList);
            int ModeFinalvalue = Modevalue + 1;
            SelectedMode(ModeFinalvalue);
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedModesList");
        }
    }

    public void SelectedMode(int Select)
    {
        int cmd = 0;
        int numBytes = 0;           

        cmd = ((0x8F00 & 0x7F00) | (m_slot & 0xFF));
        sendBuf[numBytes++] = Convert.ToByte(Select - 1);
    }
```

Even though I have set `SelectedIndex=1` in my xaml. When I run the app, the combobox has set of items but doesn't display the selected-index. Am I missing something here???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `SelectedIndex=1` conflicts withyour binding if `SelectedItem` with initial null value.

You can chnage the binding mode for `SelectedItem` to `OneWayToSource` so that the value in the view model won't be used for setting the selected item:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrequencyList, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedIndex="1" Name="comboBox1" />
```

Alternatively you can initialize `SelectedFrequencyList` in view model to the desired frequency:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _FreqList.Add("8 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("11.025 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("12 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("14.7 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("16 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("22.050 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("24 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("29.4 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("32 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("44.100 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("48 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("88.2 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("96 kHz");
    _FreqList.Add("undef");

    SelectedFrequencyList = _FreqList[1];
}
```

In this case you don't need to set the selected index for the combo box at all:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding FrequencyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFrequencyList, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="comboBox1" />
```

Comment: Well that's an ideal solution :) Thanks a lot :)